# Add a relation via Entityform

Tags: entities

I have created a relation called user-advisor relation between a user and a content type I named Advisor on my Drupal 7 site. I have also created an entityform type called Advisor where I have created an entity reference field that has a list of all of the Advisor content types. What I want to be able to do is have the user submit this form and when it is submitted I want to create a new user-advisor relation with the user and the selected advisor, I am curious as to what would be the best way to do this and if there is a module to do so. I have looked into the [Relation Add](https://www.drupal.org/project/relation_add) module but I am not sure if its functionality is what I need or how to use it.

Comment: Relations work between 2 endpoints that _already_ exist. It sounds like you want an Advisor content type of like topics or something. And then the Relation Add block will let you as the logged in user select things you Advise on ... I dont think you need the form even. Entity Reference and Relations are not the same thing.

Comment: Well the adivsor content I have has a relation to users so that I can render the information from both the advisor and user on other pages which is why I have the relation (multiple users can have a relation to the same advisor and vise versa) but my main problem is that I want to be able to create a form where the user can see just a list of advisors (that have already been created) they want to add and choose one and the relation is created automatically in the background if that makes sense.